# How to fix Sqlitelog (13) statement aborts at 68 error in phonegap android

Tags: jquery, android-sqlite, cordova-2.0.0

I am fetching the data from the local server and storing its data in the local table before it was working fine but know its showing this error in the logcat I checked its fetching the data from the server properly but while storing the data in the local database it creates this error

```
08-28 08:34:25.111: E/SQLiteLog(4172): (13) statement aborts at 68: [INSERT INTO crm_dynamic_form(rc_group_id,dynamic_form_id,module_id,table_id,table_name,field_name,listorder,display_name,element_type,dynamic,mandatory,list_show,rowpos,columnpos,tab_i
08-28 08:34:25.121: D/CordovaLog(4172): calling quotaUpdater.updateQuota newQuota: 0
08-28 08:34:25.131: D/CordovaLog(4172): DroidGap:  onExceededDatabaseQuota estimatedSize: 0  currentQuota: 200000  totalUsedQuota: 200000
08-28 08:34:25.131: D/CordovaLog(4172): calling quotaUpdater.updateQuota newQuota: 0
08-28 08:34:25.141: E/SQLiteLog(4172): (1) statement aborts at 2: [ROLLBACK] cannot rollback - no transaction is active
08-28 08:34:25.401: W/Trace(4172): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-28 08:34:25.411: W/Trace(4172): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Can anyone tell why its giving this error and how to solve is.
thanks id advance.....

Answer (score 0):

line 3 appears to have the answer:

> 08-28 08:34:25.131: D/CordovaLog(4172): DroidGap: 
>   onExceededDatabaseQuota estimatedSize: 0  **currentQuota: 200000** 
>   **totalUsedQuota: 200000**